# Fourier transformation, imaginary part in "time domain"

Tags: fourier-analysis

I'm currently having an issue with an assignment I'm working on. I'm not going to specify too much about the details, but it is about image processing and currently I'm specifying that the function values in the Fourier domain is only real values. The problem with this is that I end up with an imaginary part in my spatial domain. I can't wrap my head around what this actually means? Can someone provide me with some intution behind this?